# Using class decorators, can I get the type of the class-type instance?

Tags: typescript

Consider this [failing example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20DecorateClass%3CT%3E(instantiate%3A%20(json%3Aany)%20%3D%3E%20T)%7B%0D%0A%09return%20(classTarget%3AT)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*...*%2F%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40DecorateClass((json%3Aany)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20instance%20%3D%20new%20Animal()%3B%0D%0A%09instance.Name%20%3D%20json.name%3B%0D%0A%09instance.Sound%20%3D%20json.sound%3B%0D%0A%09return%20instance%3B%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20Name%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09public%20Sound%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D):

```
function DecorateClass<T>(instantiate: (...params:any[]) => T){
    return (classTarget:T) => { /*...*/ }
}

@DecorateClass((json:any) => {
    //Purely example logic here, the point is that it have to return
    //an instance of the class that the decorator runs on.
    var instance = new Animal();
    instance.Name = json.name;
    instance.Sound = json.sound;
    return instance;
})
class Animal {
    public Name:string;
    public Sound:string;
}
```

Here I want to constrain the anonymous function in the decorator to always return an instance of the class in question, but the above does not work since T is actually `typeof Animal` and not `Animal`.

In a generic function, is there anyway I can get type `Animal` from the type `typeof Animal` without being annoyingly verbose like explicitly defining all types like `function DecorateClass<TTypeOfClass, TClass>(...)`?

Unfortunately, using typeof in the generic syntax is not supported, which was my best bet in trying to get the compiler to understand what I want:

```
function DecorateClass<T>(instantiate: (json:any) => T){
    return (classTarget:typeof T) => { /*...*/  } // Cannot resolve symbol T
}
```

Comment: At first glance this seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What _exactly_ are you trying to accomplish? Seems like you are deserializing JSON into a type instance, but cannot tell for sure.

Comment: @JohnWhite No, this is is just a basic example. What I want to accomplish is to have the type of the class instance in the typings of the decorator function without explicitly having to define it. This structure is going to be applied on hundred of classes, I want the inners of the decorator to be typed to the instance of the class, and I really don't like the idea of having to explicltly define the type of the instance of the class the decorator runs on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hold the line just for a second...*

Recently I've needed a type definition for a function that takes in a class as an argument, and returns an *instance* of that class. When I came up with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500861/type-for-function-that-takes-a-class-as-argument-and-returns-an-instance-of-tha/36501062#36501062), this question soon came to my mind.

Basically, using a newable type it is possible to conjure a relation between a class and its instance, which accurately and perfectly answers your question:

```
function DecorateClass<T>(instantiate: (...args: any[]) => T) {
    return (classTarget: { new(...args: any[]): T }) => { /*...*/ }
}
```

---

### Explanation

In TypeScript, any given newable type can be defined with the following signature:

```
new(...args: any[]): any
```

This is analogous to *a newable type (the constructor function) that may or may not take arguments and returns `any` (the instance)*. However, nothing says it must be `any` that is returned -- it can be a generic type as well.

And since we have exactly what is returned from the constructor function (by type-inferring the class the decorator is applied to) inside a generic type parameter we can use that to define the return type of the passed in callback function.

I've tested the decorator, and it seems to be working precisely as expected:

```
@DecorateClass((json: any) => {
    return new Animal(); // OK
})
@DecorateClass((json: any) => {
    return Animal; // Error
})
@DecorateClass((json: any) => {
    return "animal"; // Error
})
class Animal {
    public Name: string;
    public Sound: string;
}
```

This effectively invalidates my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374498/2788872).

---

### Edit: Inheritance

When inheritance is involved (eg.: a derived type is to be returned from `instantiate`), assignability seems to be flipped: you can return a *base* type, but not a *derived* type.

This is because the returned type from `instantiate` takes precedence over the "returned" type of `classTarget` during generic type-inference. The following question examines this exact problem:

- [Generic type parameter inference priority in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36835363/2788872)

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

*It turns out what you are asking for is entirely possible. I've added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36569579/2788872) but will leave this one here as well, as it might contain information valuable to someone. This answer suggests a runtime solution, the new one suggests a compile-time solution.*

---

I'd say your best bet is runtime type checking, as you *will* have the correct type inside the decorator function:

```
function DecorateClass(instantiate: (...params: any[]) => any) {
    return (classTarget: Function) => {
        var instance = instantiate(/*...*/);

        if (!(instance instanceof classTarget)) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

This will not yield compile-time type safety.