# Type for function that takes a class as argument, and returns an instance of that class

Tags: typescript

I have an instantiator function that returns an instance of the provided class:

```
declare type ClassType = { new (): any }; // alias "ParameterlessConstructor"

function getInstance(constructor: ClassType): any {
    return new constructor();
}
```

How could I make it so that the function returns an *instance* of the `constructor` argument instead of `any`, so that I can achieve type safety for consumers of this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Well, this was mortifyingly easy, I just had to bypass the boundaries set by my own code.*

---

The key is specifying the `constructor` parameter to be *a newable type that returns a generic type*, which is the *same* generic type `T` returned by the `getInstance` function:

```
function getInstance<T>(constructor: { new (): T }): T {
    return new constructor();
}
```

This will yield the correct results:

```
class Foo {
    public fooProp: string;
}

class Bar {
    public barProp: string;
}

var foo: Foo = getInstance(Foo); // OK
var bar: Foo = getInstance(Bar); // Error: Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'Foo'
```