# TS2322: 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'SuperClass'

Tags: typescript

I have a base class which has a large number of subclasses.

```
class SuperClass{
    constructor(){}
}
class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{
    constructor(){super()}
    SubClass1Prop(){}
}
class SubClass2 extends SuperClass{
    constructor(){super()}
    SubClass2Prop(){}
}
```

I have a list which contains a mix of different subclasses, and I have declared its type as `SuperClass[]` because they share that common ancestor.

```
let list:SuperClass[] = [];
list.push(new SubClass1());
list.push(new SubClass2());
```

I have a function which takes a SubClass as a parameter, then filters the list to return instances of that SubClass.

The type declaration from this function is taken from this SO answer ([Type for function that takes a class as argument, and returns an instance of that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500861/type-for-function-that-takes-a-class-as-argument-and-returns-an-instance-of-tha)) with the minor difference that I am returning a list instead of a single object.

**The error is right here. I control what types can be passed into the filterList function and can guarantee that it will always be a child of SuperClass. However, TypeScript has no way of knowing this. How do I declare that that any className I pass to this function MUST always be a child of SuperClass, and cannot be an "arbitrary type"?**

```
function filterList<T>(className: { new():T }):T[] {
    //TS2322: Type 'SuperClass[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.   
    // Type 'SuperClass' is not assignable to type 'T'.     
    // 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'SuperClass'
    return list.filter(obj => obj instanceof className);
}
```

Sample usage scenario for the above function. (removed null safety checks to simplify for demonstration purposes)

I require that filteredList be correctly identified as having the type `SubClass1[]`, and not the type `SuperClass[]` or `any[]`, without explicitly type casting using the "as" keyword. Currently all these requirements are met, but the TS error is in the function above. Any solution must not break the type checks here.

```
let filteredList = filterList(SubClass1);
filteredList[0].SubClass1Prop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is quite a lot easier, you can use [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) along with [generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) to achieve the same effect:

```
function filterList<T extends { new (...args: any): any }>(className: T): InstanceType<T>[] {
    const isT = (potentialT: any): potentialT is InstanceType<T> => {
        return potentialT instanceof className;
    }
    return list.filter<InstanceType<T>>(isT);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJwMLigbwLAChojpgB7AOwgBdV5grTUAKASmwF8DP9RIYEARpj4BGaMgAeVZOQAm-JGmE4CxEhWq16jVtgiLmLbmsHKIIgAqpSiXd268oceEKwQATOKkz5zlBjc8QmIySho6BkM9A1ZjYlM3dysbOy4CdPwQZCpoEABLagAuBH8zAG0AXWgAXmhKgG4CfOoAOkR4CAALJnJkAHdnV1FWFkbMgqo2ju7egYS+dxGxggAzeHJ6PIpoFbyQaVQAGQmAHgAVL2k5GGxoWegmFqewVABzCELoMHIATxZP74-aDsAB8TEcEAAcmAALbIT5nf7QACSYW+wGQZx+KHOIMq0CCalC1GgBQutSYiFIVyoeTAIDOAN+SKpNLpDNJMFR1HRmOxyFxNRBBNUamIqGy8FQ5GgrJktPpFzyaI2yFIKxIbmhcLGajiRAlVClMuak12+zQJ25VF5WJxZxBYLJozS+AyWRy5oOyFkxxJtS9aD9VCY8ygIhd+EDEt9EzKAAYKi0w+ZkrZI0A)

Comment: I understand the type guard and I like how it can be directly used as the filter callback. However InstanceType is new to me and the linked handbook description is not too clear. Does it mean that `potentialT` is constructed from class `T`? With reference to the handbook, why are you able to use `InstanceType<T>` instead of `InstanceType<typeof T>`, and why is `InstanceType<Function>` invalid? Aren't Classes technically Functions?

Comment: @dreamturtle, `InstanceType` specifies the type of an instance of a class (like you said), but `T` is a type, rather than a value (i.e. it is already `typeof className`), for TypeParameters you can look at [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types). Lastly, TypeScript discriminates between functions and classes (classes are a subset of functions in TS).

Answer (score 1):

`list` is type `SuperClass[]`, and so filtering it will give you back another `SuperClass[]`, therefore the function returns type `SuperClass[]`. However, according to the type of the function, it actually returns type `T[]`. If `T` satisfies `SuperClass`, such as in the example ways that you're calling it, then happy days. But if `T` didn't satisfy `SuperClass`, then the filtered list you're returning would simply not be assignable to the actual return type of the function. To fix this, you just need to ensure that `T` satisfies `SuperClass`. This is easily done with the type parameter `T extends SuperClass`.

You should always constrain your type parameters (see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)), unless their types literally don't matter, even if it doesn't error. It simply does not make sense to call `filterList()` with a class that doesn't satisfy `SuperClass`, and so you should tell the compiler to stop you if you try. In this case, it stopped you without you even trying, because it identified it as inherently unsafe.

You'll note that making that change, though, gives you another error:

> 'SuperClass' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SuperClass'.

The problem here starts off the same as before: the function returns type `SuperClass[]`, but it's typed as returning `T[]`. If `T` *is* `SuperClass`, then happy days. But if it isn't, and `T` is a subclass of `SuperClass` with additional members, then `SuperClass[]` would not be assignable to `T[]`.

It may be counter-intuitive that the filtered list is actually type `SuperClass[]`, given that you're clearly filtering out everything from the array that isn't type `T`, suggesting that the filtered array should be type `T[]`. But it doesn't quite work that way. The type guard `obj instanceof className` creates semantic meaning that `obj` is type `T`, and so from that point on the callback, the compiler would know that. However, that meaning is not provided to someone calling that callback. Your `Array.prototype.filter()` call doesn't know what types satisfy its callback, because the callback doesn't tell it. All it knows is that the array it's filtering is type `SuperClass[]`, and so the best it can say is that the resulting array is also of type `SuperClass[]`.

The solution to this is simple: you just need to provide a type predicate (see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)) on your callback. From this, `filter()` will know what types satisfy its callback, allowing it to accurately say what type the resulting array is.

```js
const foo: SuperClass[] = list.filter(obj => obj instanceof className)
const bar: T[] = list.filter((obj): obj is T => obj instanceof className)
```

So, with both these fixes, your `filterList()` function now looks like this:

```js
function filterList<T extends SuperClass>(className: { new():T }):T[] {
    return list.filter((obj): obj is T => obj instanceof className);
}
```

### Aside

I'm dubious about what you're trying to do here; in abstract, I'm not sure that this is a good idea. You should know that class inheritance itself doesn't have semantic meaning in terms of types. Given `class A {}`, `new A` would be assignable to type `SuperClass`. It's not a matter of `A` actually being related to `SuperClass`, but of `A` satisfying `SuperClass`. I don't think there is any way in your `filterList` function to actually enforce that `T` is a subclass of `SuperClass`.

Comment: "Given class A {}, new A would be assignable to type SuperClass." Yes this would be true for this toy example, but in real code SuperClass will have properties and/or methods that are inherited by all subclasses but will likely be absent in unrelated classes. That said, does there exist a way to declare that some variable MUST be a descendant of some `SuperClass` rather than just having the same property/method names? Checking that the properties fit is semantically different from checking that some ancestor class exists in the object's prototype chain.

Comment: As I said at the very end there: I don't think so. I've never had to think about this before, so I tried to do some research on this for your question, and I couldn't turn up anything. I think class inheritance itself is simply not a concept that exists within the type system (with the exception of `super()`); an object is simply defined by its properties. This is part of the reason why I'm dubious about you investing so much into class inheritance like this; I'm just not sure that this is fundamentally a good approach to managing objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add an answer because I discovered some new information (regarding abstract classes) that was not explicitly asked by the original question.

```
function filterList<T extends SuperClass>(className: Function & {prototype: T}): T[] {
    return list.filter((e): e is T => e instanceof className);
}
```

This solution is based on the one given by matthewlucock (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63323255/14073412).
The difference here is that the type of the function parameter is `Function & {prototype: T}` instead of `{ new():T }`.

The key issue is that abstract classes are not constructable ("newable"). If one wants to pass an abstract class to `filterList()` and be able to get all objects which implement the abstract class, using `{ new():T }` will fail with the error:

> Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.(2345)

The intersection with `Function` is necessary to assure that the passed argument is a function and not a regular object. Without it, you cannot use the `instanceof` operator:

> The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.(2359)

Note that although this solution allows abstract classes to be passed to the filter function, as a tradeoff, you lose some type safety in ensuring that the passed parameter is actually a class. Attempting to call `filterList` with a non-class function gives no TypeScript error:

```
function NonConstructibleFunction(){}
filterList(NonConstructibleFunction);
```

However, TypeScript will catch errors from accidentally passing in an unrelated class, provided that the shape of the class properties/methods do not match. Note that the constructor shape is not checked.

```
class UnrelatedDummyClass{
    constructor(differentConstructorParameters:number){}
}
//Property 'commonFunc' is missing in type 'UnrelatedDummyClass' but required in type 'SuperClass'.(2345)
filterList(UnrelatedDummyClass);
```

See demo: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJwMLigbwLAChojpgB7AOwgBdV5grTUAKASmwF8DiTSBbXigDF45YKzyFuxMpVIhkAOhCkA5kwBEZfkJHBoAM1R84SNJkgR1LLsU747oCyYBG5qAEZoyAB5Vk5ABMYBBQMLAgJbhlqWnpGcQhTZhY7KL4BcmFRcRspHll5JVUNLQysvVIANzRUAEsA5GhnAE8XNwh3K1zoVOJE13D3cpzJPOi5RWU1dRFagEd4Rt5kKgALUgDoUn02wa7RnoI7MGcYsHoScOgAQVOac6p2r19-IJNQ9sjiRCM-emRNtEaHQGMlsIlQqxekQTmcLrVyKs0LUqCd5MMWAAuSqkeoAbiOBEcUGg6AowFQK2Q7U8Pj8gRgtzhj3CXyIQNioISSSh3QRSLqqOc6N0Izy7IoEAmRWmAElEcihSLRNBarxEPJluQ-JsWqTyZS-DT9tw7A4rmTRIbqeEAEzPelvJn3eifbockHxNgQtC8g78xVo5AYtlScaFKYaeUClFB8qq9Wa-w6pqtS0UqntW0m2yE-DEmAAVXIlPAOoAIvB+M03QcPXFmAFavp9Ghk5aYp7UAAFMCoMDLPyoCCY8hV5xoNhmgj6XRUWoUaAAOQoHeB9FqwuDc4X5HEdgI8io0BAtWomJCZnCAG0ALrQAC80DvBPwp+oCkQ8AgqyY5GQADu7xXhYrAsK+75UJ+36-v+QEIAMFjuGBEFnlBX4-n+gH6lamaDChh5odBmFwThGZGnaBH4DOO6LvotQgEOAAyaEADwACoOq8wRJO0AB8TAFkuA7IJi0DlPOi4AGTQNgPykAwVDNCgYnsewWLQOxd6yQQACQhrwKg5AnkR9GMb6TDIBpjRnppj58V4qqUKiojINslwWMJyzgXmh4rNA-TuCx1CPgYDHMWhTAITSPn4IFwVUNeAAMt4KKUOjZLF8VoclqX9DSGIQf5sIuiyFiyomyBaqikmUKFZkRdQTDOv2rrhLF+jxEeWzOAAVlsOwla1ZVQBVGpVcmYC1RAbDdKQfUKAGgpxqKsUHvgAD0G1rLZtnAGA8AqKsx56uxynILAFK1Igx6QNAYDGTUjDQGsD0ANYwAw0C8GevBTcAqwIio0DyaE87ICOBBbd2Rhg60ADk6WZLo8OqjAP1QEDTkved0Dw8WpZTQClbVu0qPOPAx6UgstSUpsCI4ygeOXmEFjwwoTC2gAzAALAArNYm0bQ1aAJUwBPIGWxNVrwNbta+UPbYDMC2ZUYCngEM7haLkUruQa6cpuyobhQsVAA)

For me, this solution is preferable because in my use case I am in control of the parameter passed to `filterList`, and it is easy to avoid the logic error of passing in a non-constructable function.

I don't believe it is possible to get the best of both worlds, to have parameter safety that restricts invalid classes/functions while also allowing abstract classes that have valid concrete implementations. Please correct me if I am wrong about this (and/or post your own answer)