# Generic type parameter inference priority in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript, decorator

I have the following [class decorator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#class-decorators) [factory](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#decorator-factories) accepting an initializer function as its argument. In this `initializer` function I would like to return an instance corresponding to the involved class type (or that of a derived one):

```
function JsonObject<T>(initializer: (json: any) => T) {
    return function (target: { new (...args: any[]): T }) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```js
@JsonObject(function (json) {
    return new Animal();
})
class Animal {
    name: string;
}
```

Returning an instance of the exact class (as above) works correctly, but...

### Short Version

Returning an instance of a derived class does *not*. I can return a *base* instance, but not a *derived* one. I can't, for example, return a `Cat`:

```
@JsonObject(function (json) {
    return new Cat(); // Error.
})
class Animal{
    name: string;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    color: string;
}
```

... even though a Cat *is* an Animal. I can however, return an *Animal* instead of a Cat (which is wrong, as an Animal is not necessarily a Cat), for a Cat:

```
@JsonObject(function (json) {
    return new Animal(); // OK, but it shouldn't be
})
class Cat extends Animal {
    color: string;
}
```

---

### Long Version

#### The JsonObject Decorator Factory

The `JsonObject` function is analogous to *a function with a generic type parameter `T`, accepting a callback function returning a `T` as its argument, and returning a function accepting a newable type returning a `T`*. The latter (the returned function) is the [class decorator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#class-decorators) itself, obviously.

The compiler won't allow me to -- for example -- return a string from this `initializer` function (or any other mismatching type), which is as it should be.

#### Problem with Subtypes

However, the above type signature behaves in the exact opposite way when subtypes are used: from the `initializer` function I can return a *base* type, but not a *derived* type -- the following error occurs when used on the middle class of a 2-step inheritance pattern:

```
@JsonObject(function (json) {
    // Test case: return a base type.
    return new Animal(); // OK, but it shouldn't be: an 'Animal' is not a 'Cat'
})
@JsonObject(function (json) {
    // Test case: return an exact corresponding type.
    return new Cat(); // OK, as it should be
})
@JsonObject(function (json) {
    // Test case: return a derived type.
    return new Kitty(); // <-- Error, but it should be OK, a Kitty *is* a Cat
})
class Cat extends Animal {
    color: string;
}

class Kitty extends Cat {
    cutenessFactor: number;
}
```

> Error: Type 'Cat' is not assignable to type 'Kitty'. Property 'cutenessFactor' is missing in type 'Cat'.

I believe I've pinpointed the origin of the error, it is caused by the compiler when inferring generics: the generic type parameter `T` is inferred from the *"T"* in `initializer: (json: any) => T`, which means the error is caused by the JsonObject function having the generic type `Kitty`, to which `Cat` is obviously not assignable as such, and therefore the class decorator cannot be used on `Cat` in this case.

I would like it so that `T` is instead inferred from the "return" type of `target`, which would solve my problem. How could I accomplish this?

Of course, when I explicitly specify the generic type parameter, it works flawlessly (but this carries redundant information):

```
@JsonObject<Cat>(function (json) {
    return new Kitty(); // OK, since type 'Kitty' is assignable to type 'Cat'
})
class Cat extends Animal { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to chain the decorators or did you mean this:

```
function JsonObject<T>(initializer: (json: any) => T) {
    return function (target: { new (...args: any[]): T }) {
        return null;
    }
}


@JsonObject(function (json) {
    return new Foo();
})
class Foo {
    foo: string;
}

@JsonObject(function (json) {
    // Test case: return an exact corresponding type.
    return new Bar(); // OK, as it should be
})
class Bar extends Foo {
    bar: string;
}

@JsonObject(function (json) {
    // Test case: return a derived type.
    return new Baz(); // Ok
})
class Baz extends Bar {
    baz: string;
}
```

If you meant the above ^ it compiles fine

Comment: Yes, I meant separate use, although regarding the class type I believe the TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize class decorators. Unless I'm missing something, it shouldn't really matter. The problem is that generic type parameter `T` in `JsonObject` is inferred from what the `initializer` function returns, instead of what the `target` constructor returns.

Comment: This compiles fine. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed it does. However, if you were to return an instance of `Bar` in the decorator applied to `Foo`, errors would arise. This happens due to how the compiler infers the generic type of `JsonObject` from what is returned there.