# infer a class constructor type in a class decorator

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to write a decorator for a class which defines a callback which takes an instance of the class as a parameter.

```js
function Decorator<T>(callback: (instance: T) => void) {
    return (constructor: new(...args: any[]) => T) => {
        // do something
    };
}

@Decorator(element => element.someMethod())
export class SomeClass {
    someMethod() {}
}
```

When I hover over `@Decorator` it says the constructor type is `new(...args: any[]) => unknown` instead of `new(...args) => SomeClass`. It works when I add a type for the generic:

```js
@Decorator<SomeClass>(element => element.someMethod())
export class SomeClass {
    someMethod() {}
}
```

However, I'd like typescript to infer the type for me. What am I doing wrong here? Is this a restriction of typescript itself?

When I add a conflicting type it does seem to detect that the types are incompatible:

```js
class OtherClass {
    otherMethod() {}
}
@Decorator<OtherClass>(element => element.someMethod())
export class SomeClass {
    someMethod() {}
}
```

This gives me the error `"Argument of type 'typeof SomeClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => OtherClass'."`
So why can't it infer the SomeClass constructor type but can see when it mismatches?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373269/using-class-decorators-can-i-get-the-type-of-the-class-type-instance

Comment: Not the same problem at all, that question nor the answer is inferring any types for a untyped decorator parameter like in my issue. They are returning a class, which makes the typescript type inference trivial. I'm trying to access a method on an instance of said class for which typescript can't infer the type, which is not the same thing.